# numbers from $1$ to $2046$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

We have randomly taken $21$ integers from $1$ to $2046$.

Show that we can take $a$, $b$ and $c$ from the previous $21$ integers in a way such that the following inequality holds 
\begin{equation}
bc<2a^2<4bc  \end{equation}

**My Attempt**:

I have found $3$ triplets of such integers, but I do not think the above inequalities hold for every triplet.

Any hints ?

Comment: It doesn't need to hold for every triplet, it needs to hold for every group of $21$ integers.

Comment: Yes but I dont think it holds but the Question is true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the 21 numbers be $x_1<x_2<\ldots <x_{21}$.

It is not possible to have $x_{k+2}\ge  2x_k+1$ (or equivalently $x_{k+2}+1\ge 2(x_k+1)$) for all $k$ as that would lead to $2047 \ge x_{21}+1\ge 2^{10}(x_1+1)\ge 2^{11}=2048$. Thus we find $k$ such that $x_{k+2}\le 2x_k$. With $b:=x_k$, $a:=x_{k+1}$, $c:=x_{k+2}\le 2b$, we have $$ bc\le 2b^2<2a^2<2c^2\le 4bc$$
as desired.

---

The above proof suggests that the conditions are *sharp* (i.e., drawing only 20 numbers from $1,\ldots 2046$, or drawing 21 numbers from $1,\ldots,2047$ might not suffice to guarantee the existence of such triples.
However, we see that already $x_3=3$ allows to pick $a=2, b=1,c=3$ with $bc=3<2a^2=8<4bc=12$. Hence we may assume $x_3\ge 4$ and obtain $x_{21}\ge 2^9\cdot (x_3+1)-1=2559$. We conclude that $2046$ can be replaced with $2558$ in the problem statement.

Further investigation shows that we can even go up to $3070$:
If $x_3\ge 5$ we find as above that $x_{21}\ge2^9(x_3+1)-1=3071$.
So we may assume $x_3=4$. If $x_2=2$, we find $x_1=1$ and have our triple; and if $x_2=3$ then $x_2,x_3,x_4$ is our triple as long as $x_4\le 10$. We conclude $x_4\ge 11$, $x_{21}>x_{20}\ge 2^8(x_4+1)-1\ge 3071$.

Comment: but 4bc shouldn't be equal or bigger it should be bigger

Comment: @TahaAkbari it is. $x<y\le z$ implies $x<z$

Comment: I say that you should proof 4bc is always bigger than a^2 but you proofed it can be equal too.also about bc you should proof its always smaller not equal.

Comment: @TahaAkbari I did that. Note that  $bc\le 2b^2\color{red}<2a^2\color{red}<2c^2\le 4bc$ implies $bc<2a^2<4bc$.

Comment: Ok that's right

Answer (score 4):

Note that for any three positive integers $a,b,c$, if $2^k\leqslant b<a<c<2^{k+1}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, then
$$bc<ac<a\cdot 2^{k+1}=2a\cdot 2^k\leqslant 2a\cdot a=2a^2,$$
and
$$bc>ba\geqslant 2^ka=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2^{k+1}a>\frac{1}{2}\cdot a\cdot a=\frac{1}{2}a^2.$$

Thus, $2^k\leqslant b<a<c<2^{k+1}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\Rightarrow bc<2a^2<4bc.$

And $b=1,a=2,c=3$ also satisfies the requirement.

Note that we can divide the integers from $1$ to $2046$ into ten parts:

\begin{align*}
& A_1=\{1,2,3<2^2\}\\
& A_2=\{2^2=4,5,6,7<2^3\}\\
& \dots \\
& A_{10}=\{2^{10}=1024, 1025,\dots, 2046<2^{11}\}
\end{align*}
If we choose $21=10\times 2+1$ integers in $[1,2046]$,we can always find three of them $x_1<x_2<x_3$ falls in the same part $A_i$. Then we can let $b=x_1,a=x_2,c=x_3$.

Answer (score 3):

Let set $S$ be the set of integers from $1$ to $2046$, we split $S$ to $S_i$s like this:

$$S_1=\{1,2,3\}\\S_i=\{s\in\mathbb{Z}\,|\,2^{i}\le s\lt2^{i+1}\}\quad (2\le i\lt10)\\
S_{10}=\{1024,1025,\dots,2046\}$$
So we have $10$ sets in total, by Pigeonhole principle there's a set which has at least $\lceil\frac{21}{10}\rceil=3$ elements from those $21$ chosen ones.

Name these three $a,b,c$ such that $c\lt a\lt b$, then try to prove these inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.And that's good that an Iranian answered my question

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: $S_9$ goes up to $511$, $S_{10}$ starts at $1024$. The numbers inbetwwen are in none of the subsets.

Comment: $S_1$ and $S_2$ have less than $3$ elements and are thus wasted space (when taken separately).

Comment: Right, as @ErickWong corrected the solution I edited it.